# Unexpected HTML result using List view JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My implementation is at : http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/list_view.html

The first entry is when the list is hardcoded. Second and third ones are when they are extracted from the server using xmlhttp object. I am unable to understand why in the 2nd & 3rd list the formatting is different.

**Original HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
lastRecord=0;
    function loadNews(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            var x = document.getElementById("sample");
            x.innerHTML = "hello";
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                  var news = document.getElementById("news_mesgs");
                 news.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
                                 $("news_mesgs").enhanceWithin();

              }
          }

          xmlhttp.open("GET", "queryNews.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadNews()">

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="news_mesgs">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/suicide-panel.jpg">
        <h2> HKU identifies a new strategy to protect flowers from freezing stress </h2>
        <p> sample description </p>
        </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="sample"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Updated HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    lastRecord=0;
    function loadNews(){
        $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
        $.get( 
        "queryNews.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
        function( data ) {
            $('#news_mesgs').append( data )
            .enhanceWithin();
        }
    );
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadNews()">

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="news_mesgs">
        <li>
        <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/suicide-panel.jpg">
        <h2> HKU identifies a new strategy to protect flowers from freezing stress </h2>
        <p> sample description </p>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="sample"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?
...

mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");    


$query = "SELECT * FROM News_Info";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        print "<li>";
        print "<h2>".$row['Title']."</h2>";
        print "<p>sample description is here</p>";
        print "</a>";
        print "</li>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: This is a typo right `<<script>`. If not, change it to `<script>`

Comment: if you're using jquery, then why roll your own ajax handler? That entire chunk of code could be replaced with a single jquery call.

Comment: @Fred yes it is not in the code

Comment: Knew it. Gotta love those.

Comment: @Marc B I'm not proficient in jquery. The list code is adapted

Comment: What I see is that the first li is having a class, which seems to be of jquery UI or similar. However, the second and third li's are not having that class. Your js is fine. If thats what you mean by formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third are added after the widget has been initialized. You therefore have to re-enhance (refresh) the widget each time you make an update to it. And you can do that using the `$(parent_of_new_content).listview('refresh')`. In your case you would have to call the following:

```
$('#news_mesgs').listview( 'refresh' );
```

Just out of curiosity, is there any particular reason why you're using plain vanilla JS for your ajax call? If you were to use jQuery (recommended) your function would be:

```
lastRecord=0;
function loadNews(){
    $('#sample').html( 'hello' );
    $.get( 
        "queryNews.php?lastRecord="+lastRecord,
        function( data ) {
            $('#news_mesgs').append( data )
            .listview( 'refresh' );
        }
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

Please note that in the above code `.enhanceWithin()` has been replaced with `.listview('refresh')`

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/Q6XpV/)

Comment: Thanks! but in my format where do i put this method call? [Just a beginner who's tweaking around. No other reason for using this code]

Comment: See the edited version of your function. I have already added the `enhanceWithin()` function.

Comment: 'Not working'? Are you getting an error? Can you provide your updated code? I have updated my code above; please update too and be sure there're no typos.

Comment: you can see my link at the top of the page: i.cs.hku.hk/~hsbashir/Project_Work/Listview/list_view.html. It looks the same

Comment: Code Updated. Please take a look at the Updated HTML

Comment: Something weird is going on could you ensure that the HTML you generate has attributes properly quoted e.g. `<a href="http://..."...` instead of `<a href=http://... ..` and let's see if that's the cause.

Comment: I have removed the image and link tag from php so that now only text is generated. The text seems to be attributed OK but the webpage view is same as before

Comment: Here's a similar post but for an earlier version of jQM. Please read up on `refresh` and `enhanceWithin()` so you understand how this works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699232/

Comment: Yes `.listveiw('refresh')` works fine. Give it a try. ... see my updated post.